# Android layout creation dynamic runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a layout dynamically like this through code instead creating through XML.
I am able design either in vertical or horizontal buttons. But I need to create both vertical and horizontal in a same layout.

Please help me to do it in easy way.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: The easy route would be to create the layout in XML - why do you need to create it in code?

Comment: check this link:http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

Answer (score 0):

**Its simple, First create the parent linear layout**

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

**set the parameters and orientation for this parent layout:**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)

parentLayout.setOrientation(VERTICAL OR HORIZONTAL);
parentLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParam);
```

Thats it , your parent layout has been generated. **Now create new layout and start adding it to this layout. For ex.:**

```
LinearLayout firstLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout secondLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout thirdLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

parentLayout.addView(firstLayout);
parentLayout.addView(secondLayout);
parentLayout.addView(thirdLayout);
```

Also you need to set the parameters for all the layout seperatly. You can optimise the code according to your need.
Hope it works!